# Grouping of users in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a set of users who are common to all of the groups and projects in the company. Presently, I have to add those "common members" individually to each and every group or project. Is there any way to group them by a name, thereby adding them to groups or projects?

For example, `A`, `B` anc `C` are the common members and can be grouped by name `X`, so that `X` can be added, instead of individually adding `A`, `B` and `C`

PS: Users are from LDAP

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/share_project_with_groups.html ?!

Answer (score 1):

> Users are from LDAP

Aynthing LDAP related would be, interm of *group synchronization*, [related to GitLab EE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap-ee.html) (Enterprise Edition)

But, if you can simply define main group for your common team, and subgroup for your specific teams/projects, you can use [EE/CE Namespaces](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group/#namespaces)

> In GitLab, a namespace is a unique name to be used as a user name, a group name, or a subgroup name.
>
> - http://gitlab.example.com/username
> - http://gitlab.example.com/groupname
> - http://gitlab.example.com/groupname/subgroup_name
>
> For example, consider a user named Alex:
>
> - Alex creates an account on GitLab.com with the username `alex`; their profile will be accessed under https://gitlab.example.com/alex
> - Alex creates a group for their team with the groupname alex-team; the group and its projects will be accessed under https://gitlab.example.com/alex-team
> - Alex creates a subgroup of `alex-team` with the subgroup name marketing; this subgroup and its projects will be accessed under https://gitlab.example.com/alex-team/marketing

(Here you can replace '`alex-team`' by '`common-team`', or any other more descriptive name)

> By doing so:
>
> - Any team member mentions `Alex` with `@alex`
> - Alex mentions everyone from their team with `@alex-team`
> - Alex mentions only the marketing team with `@alex-team/marketing`